# Template Integration

Tags: chat, elixir, elixir-mix

I am following one reference to create demo chat app in elixir and understood very well how is it working. But i am not so sure how can i create templates in Elixir to implement the same chat room in UI rather than terminal. Can anybody suggest something on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, if I'm understanding your question, you want to look at [EEx](https://hexdocs.pm/eex/EEx.html), the tool for evaluating code embedded in a string.

Check on Phoenix as well because I believe Phoenix uses EEx too.  Specifically check this: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix#template-engine-configuration

Hope it helps.